# polymorphic Bean creation via an instance factory method

Tags: java, spring, polymorphism, factory-method

When I am creating a bean via instance factory method, can I specify in the xml an argument for "factory-method" ? e.g. in the following snippet, can I specify that my factory method createAdapter() takes an argument which determines the exact type of bean instantiated.

createAdapter() -->

```
<bean id="myFactoryBean" class="..." abstract="true">
...
</bean>
<!-- The bean to be created via the factory bean -->
<bean id="exampleBean"
factory-bean="myFactoryBean"
factory-method="createAdapter"/>
```

I have several questions here:

1) can myFactoryBean is an abstract class? meanwhile, it has a createAdapter method which returns different beans based on the different input parameter?

2) the input to the factory method createAdapter, I can only know in runtime, I can't know when I tried to specify in the sprint configuration.

Basically, I have the following code base that I want to convert into spring beans, which I don't know how:

```
//abstract and factory class
public abstract class QueryAdapter
{
   public static queryAdapter createAdapter(Query query) {
       if (query instanceof QueryByCustomer) {
           return new QueryByCustomerAdapter((QueryByCustomer)query);
       } else if (query instanceOf QueryByDevice) {
           return new QueryByDeviceAdapter((QueryByDevice)query);
       }
   }
   public abstract QueryResult query();
   //some other shared methods
}

//inheritated class 1
public class QueryByCustomerAdapter extends QueryAdapter
{
    public QueryByCustomerAdapter(QueryByCustomer queryByCustomer) {

    }

    @Override
    public QueryResult query() {
    }
}

//inheritated class 2
public class QueryByDeviceAdapter extends QueryAdapter
{
        public QueryByDeviceAdapter(QueryByDevice queryByDevice) {

}

@Override
public QueryResult query() {
    }
}
```

Comment: So the argument of the method would be created at runtime? is it changeable or is it static?

Comment: the argument 'query' will passed in at runtime, which is a polymorphic type itself. That's why I need a factory method to create corresponding queryAdpater

Comment: can you give an example of what you like to acheive?